# Get screen height and width in cosmos C#

Tags: c#, operating-system, .net-2.0, cosmos

How would I get the screen height and width in C# Cosmos?

I'm making a OS and I'm doing GUI and I need the center point for a welcome text.

Like:

```cs
int centerX = SCREENWIDTH / 2;
// and
int centerY = SCREENHEIGHT / 2;
// Would get the center
```

Comment: What C# frameworks are you using? WPF? Windows.Forms? Also, what do you mean you are writing an OS?

Comment: I'm in **.NET Core 2.0** (I have to because Cosmos only supports that) and I'm using **[COSMOS](https://gocosmos.org)** (C# Open Source Managed Operating System) To make the OS @MichaelWelch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the columns: `canvas.Mode.Columns`.
To get the rows: `canvas.Mode.Rows`